# Is Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap.php hanging up my server?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-framework2, gmail-imap

I am trying to learn/understand Zend Framework for retrieving e-mail messages via IMAP. Our web host doesn't have the IMAP extension enabled on our web server and I have osTicket installed. I want to replace the IMAP function references in osTicket with correlating Zend_Mail references, but to do that I need to understand Zend_Mail a little better.

I have the Zend Framework 2.2.5 and have done my best to read through the documentation, but most of the documentation is really directed at prior versions and while I am doing my best to adjust to read for the updated version, there are some things I am just not understanding.

I have created a test script to get me started, but I'm not understanding what is really happening here and am hoping for a little direction. Here's my script (personal details have been obviously modified for anonymity sake):

```
<?php
/*******************************************************
* simple php script to verify zend mail functionality  *
*                                                      *
********************************************************/

define('ROOT_DIR',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
define('SUPPORT_DIR',ROOT_DIR.'support/');
define('INCLUDE_DIR',SUPPORT_DIR.'include/'); 
define('ZEND_DIR',INCLUDE_DIR.'zend/library/'); //ZendFramework-2.2.5

$root = ROOT_DIR;
$support = SUPPORT_DIR;
$incl = INCLUDE_DIR;
$zendir = ZEND_DIR;

var_dump($root);
echo "\n";
var_dump($support);
echo "\n";
var_dump($incl);
echo "\n";
var_dump($zendir);
echo "\n";

echo "Include Imap... ";
include_once(ZEND_DIR.'Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php');
if ((include_once(ZEND_DIR.'Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php')) !== 1)
{
    echo 'Include Imap failed.';
    echo "<br>";
}

chdir($zendir);
echo getcwd() . "\n";

$mail_config = array(
    'host' => 'imap.gmail.com',
    'user' => 'support@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'password',
    'ssl' => 'SSL',
    'port' => 993
);

var_dump($mail_config);
echo "\n";

$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($mail_config);
var_dump($mail);

echo "\n";
var_dump($count = $mail->countMessages());

?>
```

This appears to run without any errors, except nothing happens after the include_once statement. This is what gets returned to my screen:

> string(57) "/usr/home/username/public_html/domain.com/"
>
> string(65) "/usr/home/username/public_html/domain.com/support/"
>
> string(73)
>   "/usr/home/username/public_html/domain.com/support/include/"
>
> string(86)
>   "/usr/home/username/public_html/domain.com/support/include/zend/library/"
>
> Include Storage\Imap...

It doesn't show the getcwd(), or the var_dump's for either the array or the count of messages. I even tried changing my if statement verifying the include_once worked to echo a statement if it was successful and that didn't display.

Is the script getting hung up in zend\mail\storage\imap.php? What am I not doing correctly here? Like I said, I'm trying to learn it and have been searching high and low for code examples that use v2.2.5, but I obviously missing something. What is it?

**EDIT:**

phpinfo() did not show a location for my error logs, so I added the following to the beginning my test script:

```
ini_set('track_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
error_log($php_errormsg,3,"/usr/home/username/public_html/domain.com/support/test/error_log.log");
```

It created the "error_log.log" file, right where it was supposed to, but it's empty and Runscope didn't see the script run?

Comment: There was an error, it's just not showing it on your screen. Check your error log. Come back with error ;) (it is your include though)

Comment: For testing purposes I have been running these scripts through Runscope and it runs with Status 200. Where would I look for the error logs (I'm fairly new to php as well)? FWIW - I swapped out Imap for Pop3 and got the same result.

Comment: @mittra Do `<?php phpinfo();` and check the value of `error_log`. That should contain the path to your error log. If it's a shared host it might be in a `log` folder or a file named `error_log`.

Comment: Nuts: error_log no value

Comment: PHP will log errors to the web server error log if no other location has been specified, so check there (e.g. `/var/log/apache2/error.log` if you're using Apache on an Ubuntu/debian system)

Comment: I am unable to view the error logs located at /var/log/apache2/error.log because when I try to access /var/log I get 553 Permission Denied in my ftp client (Filezilla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to follow a ZF1 example but using ZF2, which is understandable, but unfortunately won't work.

Firstly, install Composer - http://getcomposer.org/ - it just makes everything easier. I'd recommend going for the 'global' installation option (which the rest of this answer will assume you've done).

In the root folder of your project, create a `composer.json` file (which lists the project's dependencies). In it, put:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zend-mail": "2.*"
    }
}
```

this lists Zend Mail as a dependency and also PHP 5.3.3 (which ZF2 requires as a minimum).

Run `composer install` to install these. You'll see some output as it downloads the files. Once it's done, it should have created a folder called `vendor` into which it's installed the ZF2 mail class.

Your whole script can then be simplified to this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail_config = array(
    'host' => 'imap.gmail.com',
    'user' => 'support@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'password',
    'ssl' => 'SSL',
    'port' => 993
);

$mail = new \Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap($mail_config);

$count = $mail->countMessages();
var_dump($count);
```

You can remove the copy of ZF2 you put in `zend/library/` (assuming you're not using it for anything else).

Comment: I appreciate the pointers, Tim, but I don't think it is going to really solve my issue. I am creating this test script to get a better understanding of the Zend Framework so I can modify the scripts for osTicket to use Zend Mail instead of IMAP functions. Do you know where I can find documentation and examples for ZF2?

Comment: I gave you a working example that does exactly what you were attempting to do in your test script, I'm not sure what else I can provide. I would still recommend using Composer even if you're trying to integrate this into an existing application.

Comment: I am unable to install Composer. Our host apparently has "allow_url_open" disabled and I can't modify the .ini file and using "php -d" is of no help either. What I really need, I guess, is up to date documentation and coding examples for ZF2 so I can work out the correlation between IMAP functions and Zend Mail functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "the root folder of your project"? I have managed to install Composer, but it's installed to /usr/home/username because that apparently is where SSH takes me when I log in via PuTTY. I have worked out how to change directories, but want to be sure I move to the correct directory. I am still trying to work all of this out, but as a rookie and self-taught programmer, this is all pretty frustrating. All of the documentation assumes you understand how all of this works, which I don't.

Comment: I would suggest you try and get this working on your local machine, rather than trying to develop on the live server which you have limited access to. Then transfer the files up once it's done.

Comment: I tried to do the standalone Windows installation, but I don't have php.exe on my machine, so I couldn't set it up. Until I have this working, the ticket system isn't officially live, so I'm free to screw with it and can completely reinstall it if it gets screwed up.